# Java Servlet - cannot find symbol - Objects in the same folder

Tags: java, mysql, apache, oop, servlets

I've writed the following two classes:

Equipment.java

```
class Equipment{

  private int id;
    private String name;
    private String local;

  public void setId(int id){
    this.id = id;
  }

  public void setName(String n){
    this.name = n;
  }
  public void setLocal(String l){
    this.local = l;
  }

  public int getId(){
    return this.id;
  }

  public String getName(){
    return this.name;
  }
  public String getLocal(){
    return this.local;
  }

}
```

JDBCCommands.java

```
import java.util.*;
import java.sql.*;

class JDBCCommands{
  private static Connection con = new ConnectionFactory().getConnection();

  public static void Create(String name, String local){
    String sql = "insert into equipment (name,local) values (?,?)";
    try{
      PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
      ps.setString(1, name);
      ps.setString(2, local);
      ps.execute();
      ps.close();
    }catch(SQLException erro_sql){
      throw new RuntimeException(erro_sql);
    }
  }

  public static List<Equipment> Show(){
    List <Equipment> Components = new ArrayList <Equipment> ();
    String sql = "select * from equipment";
    try{
      PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
      ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
      while(rs.next()) {
        Equipment e = new Equipment();
        e.setId(Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("equip_id"))  );
        e.setName(rs.getString("nome"));
        e.setLocal(rs.getString("local"));
        Components.add(e);
      }
      rs.close();
      ps.close();
      return Components;
    }catch(SQLException erro_sql){
      throw new RuntimeException(erro_sql);
    }
  }

  public static void Update(int id, String name, String local){
    String sql = "update equipment set name = ?, local = ? where equip_id = ?";
    try{
      PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
      ps.setString(1, name);
      ps.setString(2, local);
      ps.setInt(3, id);
      ps.execute();
      ps.close();
    }catch(SQLException erro_sql){
      throw new RuntimeException(erro_sql);
    }
  }

  public static void Delete(int id){
    String sql = "delete from equipment where equip_id = ?";
    try{
      PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
      ps.setInt(1, id);
      ps.execute();
      ps.close();
    }catch(SQLException erro_sql){
      throw new RuntimeException(erro_sql);
    }
  }

  public static List<Equipment> Search(String name, String local){
    List <Equipment> Components = new ArrayList <Equipment> ();
    String sql = "select * from equipment where name like ? and local like ?";
    try{
      PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
      ps.setString(1, "%" + name + "%");
      ps.setString(2, "%" + local + "%");
      ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
      while(rs.next()) {
        Equipment e = new Equipment();
        e.setId(Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("equip_id"))  );
        e.setName(rs.getString("nome"));
        e.setLocal(rs.getString("local"));
        Components.add(e);
      }
      rs.close();
      ps.close();
      return Components;
    }catch(SQLException erro_sql){
      throw new RuntimeException(erro_sql);
    }
  }
}
```

and I tested with this class, and it worked well

```
import java.util.*;
import java.sql.*;

class MainTest{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
    JDBCCommands jdbc = new JDBCCommands();
    //jdbc.Create("Teste novo", "Novo Teste");
    for(Equipment c : jdbc.Show()){
      System.out.print(c.getId() + " ");
      System.out.print(c.getName() + " ");
      System.out.print(c.getLocal() + "\n");

    }
    System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
    for(Equipment c : jdbc.Search("est n" , "est")){
      System.out.print(c.getId() + " ");
      System.out.print(c.getName() + " ");
      System.out.print(c.getLocal() + "\n");

    }
  }
}
```

the problem is when I try this class:

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

import java.sql.*;

class ListEquipment extends HttpServlet {
  protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        JDBCCommands jdbc = new JDBCCommands();

        System.out.println("<table style=\"width:100%\">");
        for(Equipamento c : jdbc.Show()){
          System.out.println("<tr>");
          System.out.print("<th>" + c.getId() + "</th>");
          System.out.print("<th>" + c.getName() + "</th>");
          System.out.print("<th>" + c.getLocal() + "</th>");
          System.out.println("</tr>");
        }
        System.out.println("</table>");
    }
}
```

It shows this error:

ListEquipment.java:13: error: cannot find symbol

```
    JDBCCommands jdbc = new JDBCCommands();
    ^
```

symbol:   class JDBCCommands

location: class ListEquipment

ListEquipment.java:13: error: cannot find symbol

```
    JDBCCommands jdbc = new JDBCCommands();
                            ^
```

symbol:   class JDBCCommands

location: class ListEquipment

ListEquipment.java:16: error: cannot find symbol

```
    for(Equipment c : jdbc.Show()){
        ^
```

symbol:   class Equipment

location: class ListEquipment

3 errors

all the files are in the same folder and the names are correct. How can I fix this?

Comment: Perhaps make your classes public.

Comment: Check whether both servlet and JDBCCommand class in the same package or not

Comment: clean your project. In eclipse go to Project -> clean. in intelij go to File -> Invalidate caches. Then compile your project. I hope this help you

Comment: @DevilsHnd I made the classes public, it didn't work.

Comment: @Prabath  The JDBCCommand is in the exact same folder that the servlet is.

Comment: @helenDeveloper  I'm not using eclipse. I am compiling the classes on linux terminal using javac. Is there enything that I can do that have similar effect in this case?

Comment: @arksdf if your project is a maven project then run `mvn clean` on the root of your project. If not then remove `target` folder and re-compile your project again

Comment: @helenDeveloper I recently discovered it I didn't put the .jar file(for the connection with MariaDB) in the lib folder, once I did that it worked.... Thanks for the help anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Just needed to put the .jar file, for the connection with MariaDB, in the lib folder, everything is ok now.